# Spring Dependency for ResponseEntityExceptionHandler

Tags: java, spring, scala, spring-boot, controller-advice

I am not be able to import correctly **ResponseEntityExceptionHandler**

```
class ControllerAdvice @Autowired()() extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{
```

What I am missing in my pom xml file?

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

try Add it inside dependency instead of the parent. parent is a base pom of your project.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
               <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added the dependency of `spring-boot-starter-parent` which does not contain `spring-web` dependency. `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` class comes from `spring-web`. So, you can add below dependency to the pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

or you can use `spring-boot-starter-web` artifact which includes `spring-web` by default.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

For more info you can look at pom of [spring-boot-starter-web](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-web/pom.xml) and [spring-boot-starter-parent](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-parent/pom.xml) you see the dependencies that those artifact includes.

Comment: Dependency added but the class is not found.

Comment: Is your IDE saying that class not found? Or when you tried to build your project it's throwing the error?

Comment: @michele I have just tired the 2nd option it is working fine for me. ResponseEntityExceptionHandler should be in `spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE-sources.jar`. Try the check if the mentioned jar is in the maven dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to add this dependency

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```